# DataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have i javascript code which i am trying to call a function from script1.js

```
//script1.js
    $(function(){

      $('#TableID').DataTable({

      //Blah Blah Blah
   });

});
```

which works fine but if i do

```
$(function(){


});
function MyDataTable(){

  $('#TableID').DataTable({

          //Blah Blah Blah
       });
}
```

i keep getting $(...).DataTable is not a function how do i work around it.. because i have an external js i want to call the function MyDataTable() to perform the action as indicted. how do i go about this?

Note: i have a layout which looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body>



@RenderBody()

 @Scripts.Render("jquery-1.10.2.js",

    "Jquery.dataTables.min.js",
    "dataTables.bootstrap.min.js",
    "Script1.js" //Note the script1.js
    )


  @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>


</html>


Page2 (view) which calls script1

 <table id="TableID"></table>
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/JavaScript">


    $(document).ready(function(){
       MyDataTable();
    })

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Seems highly unlikely, assuming those scripts are in the same place in the DOM, they are functionally the same.

Comment: Make sure you include the [required JS](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js) in both your versions of the code.

Comment: Are you including the jQuery script more than once?

Comment: Have you try to inject the dependency ? Like in a parameter of MyDaTable function with a variable contening $('#TableID').DataTable({}) ?

Comment: how is your html code? how are you adding script?

Comment: Jason P it works well on script1.js but when i cann the page that loads script2.js it gives an error.

Comment: What is DataTable? If this is a library, you'll need to include that after jQuery so that it binds to $().

Comment: @chikor.net I mean does the page include jquery.js more than once.

Comment: Make sure you are importing the datatables library. And make sure you are using the right version. dataTable != DataTable

Comment: Your explanation is lacking. But it just seems like the jQuery/dataTables inclusions isn't loaded on Page2. Plus, you don't need to wrap it in a function, as long as the initialization is within' document.ready, you could just do =  `$('#TableID').DataTable({});`

Answer (score 0):

The main difference I see is that in the first script, the initialization occurs inside `$(function() {})` while in the second one it is outside of it and it is not even called. So this change should help you:

```
$(function(){
    MyDataTable();
});
function MyDataTable(){

  $('#TableID').DataTable({

          //Blah Blah Blah
       });
}
```

Basically, the function is called after the document was loaded.

Comment: Lajos Arpad thank you for your reply but i only want MyDataTable(); to be loaded when page2 loads that is why i put it in a section scripts tag

Comment: He loads MyDataTable on Page2, he hasn't clarified that his using ASP.NET to load and render content.

Comment: Anuga Yes and that is why i added a section scripts tag, so that MyDataTable() only loads when page2 loads

Comment: yes i have $(...).DataTable is not a function in console

Comment: @chikor, then you need to make sure the location where you intend to load the script from is valid. Probably the folder the second page is in differs from the folder the first page is in.